# Strange js parameters when injecting external HTML with J QUERY

Tags: jquery, html

I use J QUERY to import external HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $.ajax({
    url: "lajk.html",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html' }); </script>
```

external HTML code lajk.html have this code inside

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="floatinglike.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){         get_counts();   }); </script>
```

But in output I got strange parameters
floatinglike.js?_=1498259883365

Why i got this parameters and how to remove them. I nead it because of pingdom tool test.
Here is example:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/18moz/http://www.pasta.hoodfood.rs/Floating-Like/new/newlajk.html

Comment: I inline js in html and that fix problem :/ I need other solution?

Answer (score 0):

easy solution is load html like this

```
$("body").load("lajk.html");
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/